# mySQL GROUP_CONCAT - Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I can get nearly what I require, from a sql query but not quite and I would appreciate some help.

I have the following three tables:

```
people
+----+-------------------------+
| id | email                   | 
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | joe_soap@hotmail.com    |
|  2 | john_doe@hotmail.com    |
|  3 | fred_bloggs@hotmail.com |
+----+-------------------------+

jobs
+----+-------------+
| id | description | 
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Plumber     | 
|  2 | Plasterer   | 
|  3 | Carpenter   | 
|  4 | Builder     | 
+----+-------------+

people_jobs
+-----------+--------+
| person_id | job_id | 
+-----------+--------+
|     1     |   1    | 
|     1     |   3    | 
|     2     |   3    | 
|     3     |   3    | 
|     3     |   1    |
|     3     |   4    |
+-----------+--------+
```

Using this query I can output all the data in the format that I require:

```
SELECT people.id, people.email,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jobs.description 
ORDER By jobs.description DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN people_jobs On people_jobs.job_id = jobs.id 
INNER JOIN people On people.id = people_jobs.person_id
GROUP BY people.id
```

As follows:

```
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| id |         email           | GROUP_CONCAT               |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | joe_soap@hotmail.com    | Plumber, Carpenter         |
|  2 | john_doe@hotmail.com    | Carpenter                  |
|  3 | fred_bloggs@hotmail.com | Plumber, Carpenter,Builder |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

By adding a WHERE clause I can optput all the people that can do a specific job:

```
SELECT people.id, people.email,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jobs.description 
ORDER By jobs.description DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN people_jobs On people_jobs.job_id = jobs.id 
INNER JOIN people On people.id = people_jobs.person_id
WHERE jobs.description = 'Plumber'
GROUP BY people.id

+----+-------------------------+--------------+
| id |         email           | GROUP_CONCAT |
+----+-------------------------+--------------+
|  1 | joe_soap@hotmail.com    | Plumber      |
|  3 | fred_bloggs@hotmail.com | Plumber      |
+----+-------------------------+--------------+
```

What I want to achieve is the above output plus the other jobs that the people can do as follows:

```
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| id |         email           | GROUP_CONCAT               |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1 | joe_soap@hotmail.com    | Plumber, Carpenter         |
|  3 | fred_bloggs@hotmail.com | Plumber, Carpenter,Builder |
+----+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING` clause instead:

```
SELECT people.id, people.email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jobs.description 
       ORDER By jobs.description DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN people_jobs On people_jobs.job_id = jobs.id 
INNER JOIN people On people.id = people_jobs.person_id
GROUP BY people.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN jobs.description = 'Plumber' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

`HAVING` filters out people *groups* not having at least one job description equal to `'Plumber'`, whereas `WHERE` operates per row, excluding all *rows* not having a job description equal to `'Plumber'`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0d61b/1)

Comment: I've corrected typo in `CASE WHEN`. Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99c71/3/0 if anyone wants to play with it

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos Thank you so much for continuing my education. Seems there's always something new for me to learn about SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your first query with subquery and use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT people.id, people.email,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT jobs.description 
     ORDER By jobs.description DESC SEPARATOR ', ') AS jobs
   FROM jobs
   JOIN people_jobs On people_jobs.job_id = jobs.id 
   JOIN people On people.id = people_jobs.person_id
   GROUP BY people.id) AS sub
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Plumber', sub.jobs) > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99c71/4/0)**</kbd>

But it will be slower than `HAVING` approach in [Giorgos Betsos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984576/5070879) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can add a simple `having` clause, similar to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT j.description ORDER By j.description DESC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM jobs j INNER JOIN
     people_jobs pj
     On pj.job_id = j.id INNER JOIN
     people p
     On p.id = pj.person_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(j.description = 'Plumber') > 0;
```

Also, you probably do not need the `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`, unless your tables have duplicates.